# Kissing when one person is meaty and the other is milky

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, kissing

I know that someone cannot eat milk immediately after meat and vice versa. Is it ok for two people to kiss if one person has just had meat and the other has just had milk? Do they, perhaps, need to wash their mouths beforehand?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Anonymous., and thanks for bringing your question here! Please note that the site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer rabbinic advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and use that info to inform a discussion with your rabbi about a practical halachic ruling. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: This is one of the most entertaining questions on this site!  Kudos to you, and I don't understand why anyone would downvote it.

Comment: I was once in shul when someone asked the rabbi "If you're eating meat, and your wife dairy, when can you two kiss?" Before the rabbi could respond his wife called out "when he does the dishes!"

Comment: Greenspan would say 'What kind of Shalom Bayis is there when one is eating meat and one dairy?Shoyta!'

Answer (score 5):

R. Yosef Elnekaveh answers your question ([original Hebrew here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%96%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/1130077-0/) and [English translation here](http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.com/2022/03/interesting-psak-kosher-kiss-without.html)):

> אם כך, אם אתם אוכלים באותו הזמן היא חלבי ואתה בשרי ובהיותכם שמחים חשקה נפשך לנשק אותה, נקה את ידך ושטוף את פיך לבל יגע האוכל הבשרי בפיה ואולי תאכלנו ובזה תצא מכל החששות והספיק ספיקא הגם שהיא אינה אוכלת אותך, ואתה לא אוכל אותה וממילא כדרכם של המדיים והפרסיים ראוי שתנקה את עצמך לכבוד אשתך זו השכינה.
>
> ואם כבר עשית מעשה ונישקת אותה מבלי שטוף פיך סביר להניח שלא נכשלתם
> באיסור בשר וחלב שזהו ספק רחוק ביותר. ולגבי המתנה ושהיית זמן של שש שעות
> בין נשיקה לנשיקה היות ואין כאן אכילה אלא רק חשש נגיעה אינך צריך להמתין
> ודי בניקיון פיך וידך ואין לך להמציא הלכות המתנה חדשות אשר לא שערום
> אבותיכם ואמותיכם.
>
> if you are eating together, one dairy and the other meat and you get
> so happy together that you wish to kiss, **you should first clean your
> hands and wash out your mouth to avoid any doubt, even though you are
> not eating each other**, but to avoid any doubt and you should be clean
> like the custom of the Persians to honor your wife.
>
> And, taking it further, if you went ahead and kissed, without washing
> out your mouth first, the issue is very doubtful and it is likely you
> have not transgressed the laws of milk and meat together. And being
> that there is no eating involved when kissing, the concern of waiting
> 6 hours after the kiss is not relevant - with touching meat and milk
> you just have to wash off the surface, so wash out the mouth and
> hands, and new laws do not need to be formulated.

Comment: וממילא כדרכם של המדיים והפרסיים ראוי שתנקה את עצמך לכבוד אשתך זו השכינה what "ways of the Persians and Medians" is he referring to?

Comment: @Deuteronomy might be related to the customs of the Persians and the Medes related in Brachot 8b.

Comment: @Harel13 I think you nailed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine there being an issue as a person's mouth isn't yad soledes bo and is therefore unable to transfer flavour to another mouth.

If there is food stuck in between the teeth of one of the participants, I cant find a clear answer, however, there is an opinion that food stuck in someone's mouth after some time doesn't have any taste. The opinion is used to justify not restarting counting after meat if food is found stuck between the teeth. It could apply here to. Note, there are those who disagree.

> Rav Belsky in Shulchan Halevi 22:2 p. 208 writes that a small piece of food stuck in one's mouth after some time doesn't have any taste and doesn't require restarting. He didn't want to establish at what point this would be the case.

--[Waiting between meat and milk](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Waiting_between_Meat_and_Milk)

Answer (score -9):

At the very most stringent, both of you should eat a piece of bread, and bench. Beyond that, don't give it another thought.

https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/the-halachot-of-waiting-between-meals/

Must one wait after a dairy meal before eating meat?

> After eating dairy, one can eat meat so long as he does the following:
>   1. cleanses his mouth, 2. rinses his mouth, and 3. washes his hands. Some also have the practice of reciting the necessary berachot after
>   the dairy meal, waiting, and then reciting new berachot for the meat
>   meal. The need and permissibility of reciting berachot in this case is
>   a subject of halachic controversy. One may clean his mouth by eating
>   or drinking something pareve. Any solid pareve food other than dates,
>   raw flour and greens can be used. Steps 1-3 may be done in any order.

Comment: 1. Do you have a source? 2. How is both of them eating bread better than one of them doing so?

Comment: The question relates to whether there is milk residue or meat residue between the teeth of the husband and wife. And even then, whether there is the potential for mixing the milk and meat. If, one had meat and the other had hard cheese, eating bread would clear the teeth from the milk. Benching creates the separation.

Comment: But the truth is that these details relate more to the personal standing of the husband and wife. Are they both, truly, standing in such a place in terms of their personal Avodah. The most important thing is that the husband and wife are united...together, in a state of complete unity, spiritually and physically.

Comment: @WAF I have changed the formatting on this answer. This was a direct quote from the OU Kosher website link that was provided above it. My last comment was not about the meat/milk separation, but the idea that the husband and wife need to focus on agreeing in their avodah together. Particularly with younger couples, one being more zealous than the other, like on the subject of this question, can lead to marital friction. Shalom Bayit is the primary point of focus in matters like this.

Comment: Will it not be more stringent if they drink instead of benching , (why is not washing and wiping their lips not enough)