# Can you french kiss your wife if she does not eat Kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kissing

Is there any kashrut problem to kiss your wife if she has eaten something non-kosher?

Maybe you can eat small non-kosher food by kissing her.

If her whole mouth is not kosher due to the hot non-kosher food, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64581/kissing-when-one-person-is-is-meaty-the-other-is-milky

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted. It's maybe a duplicate of the one @Gershon linked but I don't think it's a bad question per se.

Comment: They aren't exactly duplicates: this one is about treif the other is about meat and milk.

Answer (score 1):

It appears not to be an issue if her mouth is empty from real food.

R Yair Spolter and R Shraga Simmons answer [here](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/When_is_a_Bracha_Not_Required$(1.pdf) (paraphrased)

> Food that is not fit for human consumption is not considered food --
>   and for instance doesn't require a bracha (see Orach Chaim 202:2 with
>   Mishnah Berurah 19).

I also heard from my Rav that food that someone (say a baby) spits out doesn't require a bracha if someone else eats it - it is disgusting and not considered food.

This is somewhat related to the question
[What should I do with food stuck in my mouth after bentching?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/what-should-i-do-with-food-stuck-in-my-mouth-after-bentching/65977#65977)
see further sources there

As always [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) before acting.

Answer (score 0):

there is no kashrus issue here. likewise you don't need separate toothbrush for meat and milk. the only appropriate response if one's wife does not yet keep kosher is the kindly and gently encourage her to start doing so at least a little bit at a time.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could add some evidence for your claim.

Comment: there isn't going to be a source that discuses it b/c it's a klotz kashya. this is why I gave the example about the tooth brushes

Comment: So how do you know you're right?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a source that directly addresses this question. It could be a source talking about a similar question or even just a svarah.

Comment: There is such a thing as a klutz teretz too.

Comment: Except that's just not how things work in the Torah. We don't suspect something with no basis to be forbidden. Random thoughts and associations don't form the basis for saying something isn't allowed. What needs to be proven is if this is in fact an issue not the other way around

Comment: @Dude there is serious potential of consuming remnants of treif food in this circumstance. The question relates to whether such circumstances are considered digestion and thereby completely Assur. That is not a suspicion or random thought. You are blowing off the question without addressing the issue or attempting to bring source for your assertion.